# Tooltip in SVG path isn't working while it works in plain html

Tags: html, css, svg

I have this very simple CSS/HTML code that works on plain HTML and shown as an example at the end of the demo too. However, it fails to work in SVG.

When inspecting the element, the `:after` code is called but the tooltip can't be seen. Any idea where am I going wrong?

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/r0Le67nc/)**

```css
    .land
    {
     fill: rgba(255,210,0,0.6);
     stroke:white;
     stroke-opacity: 1;
     stroke-width:0.5;
    }
    .land:hover{
        fill:rgb(255,210,0);
    }
    .byrne {
        display: inline;
        position: relative;
    }
    .byrne:hover:after{
        background: #333;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        border-radius: 5px;
        bottom: 26px;
        color: #fff;
        content: attr(title);
        left: 20%;
        padding: 5px 15px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 98;
        width: 220px;
    }
```

```html
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:amcharts="http://amcharts.com/ammap" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="-90 280 1040 870">
     <defs>
      
      <amcharts:ammap projection="mercator" leftlongitude="68.183544" toplatitude="37.053723" rightlongitude="97.419080" bottomlatitude="6.751085"></amcharts:ammap>
    
      <!-- All areas are listed in the line below. You can use this list in your script. -->
      <!--{id:"IN-AN"},{id:"IN-AP"},{id:"IN-AR"},{id:"IN-AS"},{id:"IN-BR"},{id:"IN-CH"},{id:"IN-CT"},{id:"IN-DD"},{id:"IN-DL"},{id:"IN-DN"},{id:"IN-GA"},{id:"IN-GJ"},{id:"IN-HP"},{id:"IN-HR"},{id:"IN-JH"},{id:"IN-JK"},{id:"IN-KA"},{id:"IN-KL"},{id:"IN-LD"},{id:"IN-MH"},{id:"IN-ML"},{id:"IN-MN"},{id:"IN-MP"},{id:"IN-MZ"},{id:"IN-NL"},{id:"IN-OR"},{id:"IN-PB"},{id:"IN-PY"},{id:"IN-RJ"},{id:"IN-SK"},{id:"IN-TG"},{id:"IN-TN"},{id:"IN-TR"},{id:"IN-UP"},{id:"IN-UT"},{id:"IN-WB"}-->
    
     </defs>
     <g>
         <a title="This is some information for our tooltip." class="byrne">
      <path id="Andhra Pradesh - 37 units" title="Andhra Pradesh" class="land" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.5" d="M374.37,881.072l-0.003,0.009l0,0L374.37,881.072z M375.185,881.023
       l-0.485,3.09l-0.941-1.338l-0.021-0.997L375.185,881.023z M374.37,881.072l-0.152-0.778l-0.34,0.55l-1.578,0.121l-0.072-0.907
       l-1.126,0.721l2.171,0.952l0,0l-0.028,1.288l0.567,0.174l0.828,1.861l-9.559,4.679l-5.865,2.304l-4.694-1.326l-3.882,0.459
       l-3.336,1.656l-3.249,7.113l0.124,1.203l-3.635,3.846l-0.342,0.577l0.48,1.08l-1.186,1.037l-3.787,0.51l-1.083-1.825l0.327-0.966
       l0.466,0.007l-0.146-0.72l-3.103-1.083l-3.91,0.753l-2.784,1.329l-2.392,1.574l-1.824,2.035l-1.81,5.579l-2.653,4.202
       l-1.344,6.258l1.744,9.312l2.203,3.861l-1.811,12.51l3.009,8.091l-0.217,4.812l2.063,5.512l-3.772-6.844l-0.705-0.319l-0.146,2.37
       l-0.771-0.772l0.443-0.765l-0.501-0.097l-1.462,2.297l2.895,2.636l1.961,0.045l1.977,1.75l0,0l0.001,1.418l-0.945-0.527
       l-1.194-2.346l-2.048-0.054l-2.162-1.571l-1.972,0.214l-0.104,0.522l1.113,0.222l0.087,0.464l-0.789-0.088l-0.275,0.756
       l-0.877,0.219l0.036,0.893l-0.805,0.362l0.551,0.808l-0.733,1.02l-1.945,0.868l-1.331-0.023l-0.536,0.595l-0.673-0.554
       l-0.858,0.816l1.665,1.303l-1.061,0.763l-0.563-0.719l-0.893,0.386l0.191-0.707l-0.595,0.118l-0.125-1.401l-2.311,0.977
       l-0.825-0.581l-0.339-1.174l-2.797-0.335l-1.42,0.549l1.319,0.58l-0.371,1.849l0.661-0.473l0.247,0.349l-0.625,0.22l0.056,0.562
       l-1.989,0.651l0.178,0.889l-1.22,0.877l-1.061-1.183l-1.284,0.151l-0.001,0.845l-0.769,0.515l-0.948,2.064l-2.188-0.183
       l-2.341-1.664l-1.707,0.233l-0.547,0.872l0.816,0.439l-1.119-0.028l-0.154-1.774l-3.403,1.089l-1.14-0.286l-0.228,1.381
       l-1.116-0.36l-0.98,1.041l0.864,1.596l-0.549-0.005l-1.145,3.958l-0.953,0.716l0.055,1.555l-0.609,0.158l-0.22-0.637l0,0l0,0l0,0
       l-0.142,0.046l-0.448-0.045l-0.127,1.07l-0.809,0.027l0.051,1.195l-2.389,0.148l-2.037-1.095l-0.682-1.037l-1.951,0.281
       l0.978-0.903l-0.171-0.997l0,0l0.535-2.527l1.623,0.006l1.107-2.158l0.861,0.877l1.504-0.146l-0.344-1.812l0.922,0.143
       l-0.167-1.821l1.388-0.566l-0.07-0.771l0.681-0.419l-0.502-0.595l1.579-0.985l-0.736-0.82l0.727-0.453l0.23-1.544l-0.571-0.999
       l-0.912,1.172l-1.284-1.397l-0.936,0.255l-0.301-0.554l-0.869,0.411l-0.635-0.438l0.795-0.329l-1.105-0.607l0.933-5.962
       l-4.268-0.243l-1.162,0.824l0.28-1.599l-0.875-0.194l-0.125-0.676l-1.962,0.357l-0.586-0.848l0.15-0.567l1.082,0.102l0.105-0.691
       l-0.64-0.623l0.872-1.163l-0.123-1.712l-1.895-1.228l-0.088,0.908l-1.377-0.235l-0.507,1.111l-0.555,0.006l-0.055-1.614
       l0.931-0.352l-0.304-1.532l-1.435,1.429l-0.644-0.91l-1.797-0.099l-0.312,0.703l0.559,1.286l-1.353,0.661l0.063,0.617
       l-1.717,0.599l-0.108,1.545l-0.345-0.768l-0.833,0.245l0.17-0.677l-0.552,0.045l-1.011,0.547l0.688,0.541l-0.405,0.21
       l-0.671-0.434l-1.035,0.726l-0.953-0.733l-0.192,1.558l-0.653-0.565l-0.115,0.726l-0.869,0.104l0.201-3.246l-1.276-0.059
       l0.415-0.961l-1.703-0.283l-1.032,0.534l-0.343-0.844l-1.478,0.477l-0.435-1.485l-0.583,0.897l-0.172-0.528l-0.684,0.571
       l-0.046-1.543l-0.551,0.472l0.171,1.147l-1.011,0.203l1.004,0.768l0.114,1.768l-1.866-0.166l-0.921,0.59l-0.882-0.872
       l-0.391,1.036l-0.494-0.263l-0.632-1.923l1.279-2.114l0.627-0.109l-0.143-0.755l-2.741-2.603l1.149-1.14l-1.256-1.661
       l-1.134-0.103l0.203-0.75l1.192-0.186l0.123-0.627l2.046,0.443l-0.301,2.001l0.402,1.203l2.549,0.297l0.686,1.355l4.348-0.89
       l1.054,1.137l-0.143,2.299l1.102-0.029l0.037,0.478l0.93-0.787l-0.516-0.72l0.6-0.875l-1.438-0.01l0.203-1.023l-1.497-0.418
       l1.812-2.159l-0.15-0.404l-1.183,0.604l0.084-0.759l0.757-0.14l0.34-0.958l2.896,0.384l-0.109-3.24l-1.087-0.011l-0.324-1.009
       l-1.484-0.406l-0.278,0.798l1.065,2.233l-0.835,0.54l-0.742-1.025l0.101-1.054l-2.083-0.183l0.041-1.478l-1.288,0.539
       l-2.087-0.716l-1.052,1.349l-0.179,1.992l-0.779,0.105l-0.673-0.811l-2.925-0.015l-0.339-0.86l0.66-0.586l-1.857-1.406
       l0.105-1.177l0.784-0.625l0.745,0.377l0.058-1.224l0.775-0.892l-2.7,0.264l-1.116-1.468l-0.729-0.125l-1.035-1.996l0.991-3.564
       l-0.464-1.201l1.79-0.665l0.411-4.306l-0.956,0.351l-1.678-0.508l0.544-1.259l-0.27-1.474l0.594-0.522l2.087,1.673l2.75,0.493
       l0.494-0.518l1.209,0.01l-0.154,0.641l0.99,0.146l1.967-3.246l-0.574-0.598l0.67-0.169l0.013-1.209l-0.975-0.738l1.132-1.021
       l-0.425-0.716l-0.85-0.112l-0.15-1.011l-1.259,0.146l-0.894-3.057l-1.491-1.503l0.04-0.417l1.431,0.172l0.07-3.612l1.365-0.515
       l0.91,0.75l0.23-0.916l-2.139-2.037l0.542-2.396l-1.089-0.233l1.144-1.826l2.028-1.118l2.76-0.464l6.817,0.999l0,0l2.537,0.246
       l1.376,0.953l1.496-0.272l2.174,0.574l2.316-0.827l2.987,0.993l0.9-1.159l0.716,1.555l1.202,0.47l0.425-0.588l1.016-0.002
       l0.401-1.391l1.516-0.774l0.489-2.765l1.559,0.059l2.341-1.402l4.015,0.665l1.515-1.151l2.529,1.955l1.606,0.081l1.609-1.726
       l0.035-1.878l0.656,0.099l0.255,1.162l0.99,0.134l-0.131-2.076l0.525-0.552l2.759-1.176l3.811,0.775l1.102-0.608l0.172-7.28
       l1.067-1.445l4.199-0.569l1.847-1.303l3.948-0.856l3.318-1.834l0.925,1.062l1.351-0.21l1.052,1.64l1.468-0.114l2.349-2.799
       l0.57-1.859l-0.958-1.056l-1.083-0.293l0.469-1.196l0.95-1.578l2.302-0.545l1.263-1.622l0.5,0.865l1.594,0.069l1.025,1.487
       l0.467,2.309l1.031,0.437l0.375,1.191l0.7-1.051l1.384,0.936l0.1,0.688l2.785,0.737l1.08-0.677l-1.296-1.006l0.272-1.202
       l0.57-0.133l-0.068-1.43l-2.43-0.591l-0.091,0.837l-3.391-1.446l0.798-1.18l-0.568-1.156l0.734-0.571l0.666,1.434l0.673,0.212
       l0.941-0.904l0.363-1.567l1.677-0.82l2.524,1.368l-0.446,0.888l2.254-0.257l2.793,1.059l0.689-0.686l0.301-2.598l1.125,0.011
       l-0.209-1.505l2.247,0.587l1.446-0.929l3.043-0.51l0.491-2.442l2.24,0.062l1.505-1.924l1.232,0.911l1.146-0.121l2.034-2.377
       l0.209-2.47l0.583-0.827l-0.544-0.549l1.785-2.675l0.143-1.044l5.384-2.892l0.272-0.562l-0.903-1.116l0,0l1.119-1.169l3.943-1.531
       l1.908-1.799l3.55,0.392l0.446,0.903l1.683,0.844l0.669-0.182l-0.008-1.693l0.81-0.375l0.2,0.662l0.635-0.073l0.094-2.79
       l0.634,0.475l0.199-0.399l-1.545-1.532l0.698-0.55l0.106-1.382l0.915-0.216l0.554-0.887l-1.533-0.292l1.309-1.424l-0.606-1.119
       l2.95-3.48l0.657,0.963l0.628-0.06l0.184,1.909l0.617-0.092l-0.486,1.319l1.71,0.571l0.282,0.608l-0.911,1.086l0.113,1.007
       l1.207,1.132l0.835-1.585l2.833-1.22l0.686-1.749l-0.446-0.679l0.601-0.54l1.197,0.812l1.039-0.081l0.188,1.257l1.067,0.426
       l2.211-0.908l0.949,0.251l0.127-1.474l-0.545,0.278l-0.577-0.699l1.935-2.565l-1.487-0.273l-0.146-0.549l0.709-0.509l-1.202-0.054
       l0.093-1.389l1.031-0.415l2.145-3.249l1.799,0.83l0.088,0.724l0.375-1.371l1.222,0.241l0.352-0.896l2.008-0.288l0.068-0.876
       l0.979,0.035l0.393-0.788l-1.692-1.855l0.879,0.099l-0.902-0.929l-0.438,1.104l-0.62-2.001l1.073-0.556l1.637,0.378l1.221,1.39
       l-0.183-1.484l0.683-0.02l0.088-0.574l-0.486-1.334l0.362-0.223l0.534,0.679l0.308-0.321l0.216,1.101l-0.526-0.056l0.049,0.433
       l0.94,0.156l0.394-1.884l0.846,0.661l0.672-1.056l-0.266-0.886l0.759-0.916l1.931,3.775l0.685,0.127l-0.456,0.734l1.048,1.844
       l0.896,0.286l-1.06-1.944l1.242-0.823l2.175,5.223l1.821,0.6l2.284-0.153l1.433,1.58l1.077-0.098l0.743-0.756l4.733-0.445
       l0.099-2.055l0.689,0.432l0.239-0.443l-0.526-0.44l0.947,0.151l-0.585-0.51l0.852,0.278l0.826-0.757l-0.361-0.671l0.655-0.793
       l-0.668-1.292l1.48,0.899l0.465-1.093l2.006-1.214l0.564,1.433l0.654-1.151l1.094,0.07l-0.008-0.792l-0.9,0.125l-0.732-1.304
       l1.814,0.056l0.101-0.96l0.97,0.153l-0.216,0.87l0.658,0.651l0,0l1.098,0.675l-4.66,5.365l-0.755,2.299l-2.305,2.181l-2.871,4.294
       l-6.031,5.628l-0.029,1.157l-10.604,5.354l-3.838,2.615l-1.126,1.884l-3.125,2.886v0.912l-1.717,2.327l-3.43,3.664l-15.853,8.033
       l-6.259,4.833l-1.853,2.335l-0.676,2.5l-0.597,0.286l0.188,1.192l1.454,1.261l1.112-0.309l-0.297,3.087L374.37,881.072z"></path>
     </a>
     </g>
    </svg>
    <a title="This is some information for our tooltip." class="byrne">Hello Tooltip</a>
```

Comment: toolitips in SVG are [title elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title), not attributes.

Comment: Also SVG content does not support the :after pseudo

Comment: Thanks. Let me have a look at other options in that case.

Comment: You're placing HTML elements inside `<svg>` elements and expect it to work. It won't. SVG is an image format and has a limited subset of elements that can be placed inside them and they do not include HTML elements. Read about SVG links [here](https://www.w3.org/wiki/SVG_Links). Furthermore, opinions won't help you here. Documentation will. SVG elements do not have pseudo-elements. It has never been implemented and while they might be implemented at some future point, they haven't been, yet.

Comment: To clarify: the `<a>` you placed inside your `<svg>` is not an HTML anchor. It is a custom `<svg>` element you created. Expect it to behave like a custom `<svg>` element, not like an HTML anchor.

Comment: So there's no solution to this?

Answer (score -2):

Did you try adding `xlink:`? It works fine with `xlink:`

https://jsfiddle.net/mohzjnf6/

Anchor tags need an `xlink:` prefix as `SVG`s is an `XML` based language (not based on `HTML` as popularly belived).

Comment: Thanks but I don't see any tooltip on the map when I hover over it. I'm on Chrome.

Comment: Since it is through `title` attribute, you need to wait for a second or two for it to appear. That's how the tooltips from `title` based attribute work :)

Comment: That's not what i want though. I want a css solution where it appears instantly.